# On page refresh on click mute button is not working for audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have a simple section with video-tag, I have added audio as background to this section, I want on click muted button the sound should play on the background

The problem:

I mean the audio plays only when user clicks muted-btn, at first everything works fine but when I refresh the page and click muted-btn the video plays but the audio on the background is not playing, but when I hit ctrl + shift + r and click the muted-btn button the audio is playing, the problem is when u normal refresh the page and click the muted-btn audio is not playing.

Note: the video sound is playing but not the audio on the background (music beat)

Here is HTML

```
 <audio id="audioplayer" playsinline controls muted loop autoplay hidden>
            <source src="audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>
```

Here is button for mute and unmute the audio on click

```
   mutedbtn.on("click", function () {
        if ($("#audioplayer")[0].muted == true) {
            $("#muted-btn").removeClass("muted");
            $("#audioplayer")[0].muted = false;
        } else {
            $("#muted-btn").addClass("muted");
            $("#audioplayer")[0].muted = true;
        }
    });
```

Here is live demo : [live demo](http://meed.audiencevideo.com)

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Based on the code in the question everything looks right. What is the `[0]` for?

Comment: so u want to say that element is causing the issue?

Comment: Seems like it is working now.